# Do you need to normalize your data before using scipy.spatial.distance.cosine() in python?

Tags: python, scipy, cosine-similarity, scipy-spatial

I have two datasets D1 and D2. Each data set has n features (columns) and the feature values have different scales. I need to find the cosine distance between each relevant pair of samples in D1 and D2 to quantify how much D1 and D2 are similar. Do I need to normalize D1 and D2 before using cosine distance? I'm using scipy.spatial.distance.cosine(u, v) to find the distance between sample u and sample v.

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

> Do you need to normalize your data before using scipy.spatial.distance.cosine() in python?

If "normalizing" the data involves only multiplying the input by a scalar, then no, you do not need to normalize.  Check out the formula for the distance in the [docstring](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cosine.html).  Now suppose *a* and *b* are positive scalars.  Then

```
cosine(a*u, b*v) = 1 - dot(a*u, b*v)/(norm(a*u)*norm(b*v))
                 = 1 - a*b*dot(u, v)/(a*b*norm(u)*norm(v))
                 = 1 - dot(u, v)/(norm(u)*norm(v))
                 = cosine(u, v)
```

So the scaling factor that you would use to normalize the input would cancel and not affect the result.

You can see this in a simple example:

```
In [17]: from scipy.spatial.distance import cosine

In [18]: u = np.array([1.0, 3.0, 5.0, 10.0])

In [19]: v = np.array([-3.0, 1.0, 0.0, 2.0])

In [20]: cosine(u, v)
Out[20]: 0.5399562937717639

In [21]: cosine(u/10, v)
Out[21]: 0.5399562937717639

In [22]: cosine(3*u, 4*v)
Out[22]: 0.5399562937717639
```

Comment: But then why when I use StandardScaler().fit_transform() and normalize the data before using  scipy.spatial.distance.cosine() I get different result than when I feed in the raw data? Plus, by reading the following link it seems normalization does effect the results:
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/292596/is-feature-normalisation-needed-prior-to-computing-cosine-distance

Comment: The question that you asked is about `scipy.spatial.distance.cosine`.  There is nothing about scikit-learn or `StandardScaler().fit_transform()` in the question.  Perhaps you should ask a new question about that.  Be sure to include a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), so readers can easily and clearly understand the problem that you have.

Comment: [`StandardScalar`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.html) shifts the data by its mean.  Using that on the inputs to `cosine` *will* affect the distance.

Comment: Thans for your reply! So the question is when different features have different scales, shouldn’t we shift the data by its mean before applying cosine?